# regular expression mysql REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following strings in the table:

```
activity_result.step1.desires
activity_result.step1.desires.one
activity_result.step1.desires.one.1
activity_result.step1.desires.two
activity_result.step1.desires.abs
activity_result.step5.habits
activity_result.step2.noroc
activity_result.step2.habits.ops
activity_result.step2.habits.ops.trei
```

I want to use REGEXP in MySQL to get just the following records:

```
activity_result.step1.desires
activity_result.step5.habits
activity_result.step2.noroc
```

I started with `^activity_result\.step([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$`. Please help how to change the reg to get the desired result?

Comment: Maybe `^activity_result[.]step[1-9]?[0-9][.][a-z]*$` or just `activity_result[.]step[1-9]?[0-9]`?

Comment: I assume that you match these line-by-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want this:

- beginning of string (^)
- activity_result (activity_result)
- a period (.)
- the word step (step)
- a number between 0 and 99 without padding ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])
- a period (.)
- any string that does not include a period ([^.]+)
- end of string ($)

So in regex that's

```
^activity_result\.step([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.[^.]+$
```

You can test this out over at https://regex101.com/

Paste in the regex, add the `gm` modifier, and paste in your sample data and it will show you the matches.

Comment: how to change that to get just: activity_result.step1.desires.one, activity_result.step1.desires.two,
activity_result.step1.desires.abs,activity_result.step2.habits.ops

Comment: @DumitruGutu: [`^activity_result[.]step[1-9]?[0-9][.][a-z]+[.][a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/sM7vZ8/1). Note that in MySQL you either need to double escape special characters or place them into character classes.